# Calling a .Net function form python which takes an argument (passed by reference)

Tags: python, ironpython, python.net

I am trying to invoke a .Net function from python using the Python.net module. The existing code was written on Iron Python, I am in the process of converting the code base to Python 3.X version.

Can somebody please help me with this? I am currently stuck at this point.

The C# function:

```
public int waitforResult (out UInt32 Elapsed_time)

{
// Code snippet
}
```

IronPython code:

```
Elapsed_time = clr.Reference[System.UInt32](10000000) - (works fine in Iron Python)
```

Pyton.net code:

```
Elapsed_time = System.UInt32(10000000)

result = waitforResult(Elapsed_time)
```

It seems the wait time is not being considered

Thanks, Lipun

Comment: Please excuse the mistakes. Posting in StackOverflow for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Python.NET bundles any `out` parameters with the return value into a tuple. So you need

```
result, elapsed = waitforResult()
```

On a similar note, this is how you call `Dictionary.TryGetValue`:

```
found, value = dict.TryGetValue(key)
```